# Removing gap between columns in splitLayout within dashboardSidebar

Tags: css, r, shiny, shinydashboard

I'm using the `splitLayout()` function within a `dashboardSidebar()` from the shinydashboard package. When I do, there is a significant gap between inputs within my `splitLayout()`.

When I used vanilla shiny, I could control this gap with parameter `cellArgs = list(style="padding: 0px")` but this seems to have a different effect within a `dashboardSidebar()`.

**Question:**
How can I control the gap between inputs inside a `splitLayout()` within a `dashboardSidebar()`?

Here is a MRE which shows my unsuccessful attempts at using padding

```
library(shinydashboard)
library(shiny)

sidebar <- dashboardSidebar(width=400,
                            sidebarMenu(
                              menuItem("Default", tabName = "dashboard", icon = icon("dashboard"),startExpanded = T,
                                       splitLayout(cellWidths = c(100,100,100,100),
                                                   textInput("a1",label=NULL,value = 1),
                                                   textInput("a2",label=NULL,value = 2),
                                                   textInput("a3",label=NULL,value = 3),
                                                   textInput("a4",label=NULL,value = 4)
                                       ),
                                       splitLayout(cellWidths = c(100,100,100,100),cellArgs = list(style="padding: 0px"),
                                                   textInput("b1",label=NULL,value = 1),
                                                   textInput("b2",label=NULL,value = 2),
                                                   textInput("b3",label=NULL,value = 3),
                                                   textInput("b4",label=NULL,value = 4)
                                       ),
                                       #see the effect of padding
                                       splitLayout(cellWidths = c(100,100,100,100),cellArgs = list(style="padding: 20px"),
                                                   textInput("c1",label=NULL,value = 1),
                                                   textInput("c2",label=NULL,value = 2),
                                                   textInput("c3",label=NULL,value = 3),
                                                   textInput("c4",label=NULL,value = 4)
                                       )
                              )
                            )
)

body <- dashboardBody(

)

# Put them together into a dashboardPage
ui <- dashboardPage(
  dashboardHeader(title = "Padding demo",titleWidth=400),
  sidebar,
  body
)
server <- function(input, output) {


}
shinyApp(ui,server)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

your problem is not the padding of the the `splitCells` - that is working fine. It has more to do with that the inputs also have padding around them. To remove this you can add the following code

```
body <- dashboardBody(
  tags$head(
    tags$style(
      ".shiny-input-container{padding:0px !important;}"
    )
  )
)
```

hope this helps

Comment: Thank you! Works perfectly.